# Typing an Em dash in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, catalina

The ability to type a *long dash* has disappeared from Catalina. Using the <kbd>**⌘**</kbd> + <kbd>**-**</kbd> key no longer works unlike previous versions. Now I just get a beep, and no EM dash.

This is across several apps including native macOS ones, and 3rd party like Adobe's.

How do I type a long "Em" dash in Catalina?

Comment: Please don't use such unnecessary block letters when other alternatives are available. Thanks to @pkamb for the  [revision](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/372667/revisions) too! [Keyboard icons & terminology](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/keyboard-icons-terminology/210#210)  on meta.apple to the rescue.

Comment: Doesn’t a double dash automatically convert to an em dash? Just like three periods convert to a single ellipses

Comment: Apple doesn't use Command for such things, only option and option shift.  You are mistaken about how you used to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The Em Dash keyboard shortcut is now: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On my Catalina laptop, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> did not do anything until I switched back the Input Sources to U.S that I had set to U+ (Unicode Hex Input).

Comment: Uncode Hex doesn't make special characters that way, instead you hold down the option key and type the hex code.  For em dash it is 2014